Unable to cross compile simple C program using clang and lld
$ cat hello.c
int main ()
{
        return 0;
}

$ clang -fuse-ld=lld -target ppc64le hello.c -o hello.o
ld.lld: error: /tmp/hello-37cf01.o is incompatible with elf64-x86-64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
clang: error: linker (via gcc) command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Simple compiling and "not" linking step works just fine.
It's when I try to link it fails.
Output of host arch: x86_64
Target arch: ppc64le

Using a full triplet --target=ppc64le-linux-gnu seems to work. I also needed -nostdlib to fix the next error.

That's because there are different libraries compiled for different triplets, and the linker needs to know which ones to link against
